# Is there a word to describe someone as striving to be the best version of himself he can be?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

I am trying to describe someone with the mentality NOT of trying to be better than others, but rather to be the best version of himself that he can be. So a sort of striving and determination, but without competition with others. Any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In psychology or philosophy, we would say that such a person is striving toward [self-actualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-actualization), or "the realization or fulfillment of one's talents and potentialities, especially considered as a drive or need present in everyone" ([definition from Google's dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&q=Dictionary#dobs=self-actualization)).

Answer (score 0):

***Normal Perfectionist***

> … a personality trait characterized by a person's striving for flawlessness and setting high performance standards, accompanied by critical self-evaluations … Normal perfectionists are more inclined to pursue perfection without compromising their self-esteem, and derive pleasure from their efforts.

*ref*: [Perfectionism_(psychology)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectionism_(psychology)) (WP)

Answer (score 0):

To strive is to put our God-given abilities into motion. In recalling the source of said abilities, we avoid the trap of pride and make good use of the word itself: to STRIVE, is a self-imposed effort to “tackle” obstacles which impede our ability to cultivate the origin of its source, God Himself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, Susan. The word 'strive' itself doesn't entail that the striving is morally good; one who gambles can strive to beat the bookie.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen certain texts of Eastern religions translate that concept into "cultivation" (of self, of character, of conduct).

Comment: Remember to include a constructive comment with your downvote.